# Not sufficient money, still transection completes

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I am integrating iPhone app with PayPal. I am transferring money from one account to other.

For now i am testing it in sandbox mode. When i transfer from account1 to account2 and even i don't have sufficient money in account1. I thought it would give me error something like "No sufficient balance", But it doesn't . It completes transection.

what would happen in this type of scenarios when my app will go live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also face the same problem a month ago.You are right it completes the transaction without any error.But one thing you have to notice that

> account amount in which you are transferring the money.You have no
> change/effect on that.
>
> When your app go online ,it will show the error or notification

That was done in my case.Just i put my app online.

Comment: in my case, it increases amount of money in the other account.

Comment: R u sure ,you dont have much balance in your account?

Comment: in your case, it wasn't transferring money?

Comment: I don't have money in my account ,it completes the transaction and don't add any amount in sellers account.

Comment: oh one thing...Have you created buyer and seller account?I remember ,the issue was solved when i pay from my buyers account to sellers account.

Comment: in my app one user can transfer money to the other user's account. There won't be seller and buyer.

Comment: ok..But my issue was solved like that i have told.I think you have accounts conflict.

Comment: I created both personal accounts as there is no need for business account.. Still i am not sure why this is happening?